# What is the name of this algebraic object and what is it isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I have an infinite, commutative semigroup $B_0$ without identity.

Every element $b$ of $B_0$ is the zero in some infinite monoid $A_{b}$. Let's call this set of monoids $A_{B_0}$

Every nonzero element of every $A_b$ is the unit in some semigroup $B_{A_b}$.

These in turn are the zeroes in new monoids $A_{B_{A_b}}$ and so on.

All of the semigroups $B_{A_b\ldots}$ are therefore the elements in a wider algebraic object, which has $B_0$ as its zero, the infinite set of monoids $B_{A_b}$ as its unit and its subsequent elements are ever-increasing sets of infinite sets of monoids.

> What is the name of this algebraic object and what is it isomorphic to?

It looks to me, like a generalisation of the notion of a Euclidean domain, with a Euclidean function having base of infinite order.

I can see that this structure describes a graph of infinite size and infinite dimension, which would have uncountable cardinality of points.  Am I right in thinking this implies that not all of the elements $\cup B_{\ldots}$ can be unique rational numbers?

Comment: Can you give us an example?

Comment: @Berci I could try to construct one but I might introduce other properties unintentionally and fail to get the most general result possible.

Comment: I'm confused about the alternation between "zero in a monoid" and "unit in a semigroup." Don't you mean the same thing by these phrases?

Comment: @Kevin Carlson did you assume they share the same group operations? The monoid has both a unit and a zero. The zero of the semigroup is explicitly excluded. If I described both with the same object, either the semigroup would gain its zero or the monoid would lose its.

Comment: Oh, by "zero" you mean an absorbing element, not an identity. I was misunderstanding.

Comment: @KevinCarlson sorry it might be me. Let me check carefully. It depends if I'm using addition or multiplication as the analogy to my operations!

Comment: @KevinCarlson yes, when I say zero I mean the analogy of a zero to the multiplication operation.  So combination with zero is absorbing and combination with the unit is nullipotent.